# How to connect Raspberry Pi Pico W to Wi-Fi using WPS?

Tags: wifi, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

My Raspberry Pi Pico W checks a stock and lights up green or red LED's based on the price. It needs to connect to Wi-Fi. I want it to read "your_wifi_details.txt" for SSID and password and connect. If it cannot connect it should enter WPS mode and the lights should flash, then user presses WPS button on router and a button on the Raspberry Pi Pico W.

How to get WPS to work on a Raspberry Pi Pico W? I'm getting:

> 'CYW43' object has no attribute 'scan_wps'

```
# If the button is pressed, scan for WiFi networks that support WPS
if not button.value():
    sta_if.scan_wps()

    # Connect to the first WiFi network that supports WPS
    sta_if.connect_wps()
```

If in "your_wifi_details.txt" I put correct SSID and password it works, but I can't have users download Thonny and edit files.

```
import urequests
import network
import time
import machine

# Set up the button (connected to pin 15)
button = machine.Pin(15, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)
print ('pin 15 set as button')

while True:
    print ('enter while true loop')
    # Connect to the WiFi network
    sta_if = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    #print ('firstline passed, sleeping for 10 seconds')

#ignore this, unnecessary now
    #for i in range (0, 20):
     #   time.sleep(0.55)
      #  print ('sleeping...')

    #print ('nap over, trying to continue..')
    sta_if.active(True)
    print ('firing up connection')

    # Read the WiFi SSID and password from the text file
    with open("your_wifi_details.txt", "r") as f:
        ssid = f.readline().strip()
        password = f.readline().strip()
        print ('read your_wifi_details.txt successfully')

    # Try to connect to the WiFi network
    sta_if.connect(ssid, password)
    print ('attempting to connect to wifi')

    # Wait until the device is connected to the WiFi network
    while not sta_if.isconnected():
        # Flash the LEDs to indicate that the device is unable to connect
        print ('connection failed, attempting to flash LEDs')
        green_led.on()
        red_led.on()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        green_led.off()
        red_led.off()
        time.sleep(0.5)

        # Set up the button (connected to pin 0)
        print ('setting up button for WPS')
        button = machine.Pin(15, machine.Pin.IN, machine.Pin.PULL_UP)

        # If the button is pressed, scan for WiFi networks that support WPS
        if not button.value():
            sta_if.scan_wps()

            # Connect to the first WiFi network that supports WPS
            sta_if.connect_wps()

            # Save the WiFi SSID and password to the "your_wifi_details.txt" file
            with open("your_wifi_details.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(sta_if.config("essid") + "\n")
            f.write(sta_if.config("password") + "\n")
            print ('wifi details written to file')

# Print the WiFi connection status in the terminal so I can see if it worked
print("Connected to WiFi:", sta_if.isconnected())
```

Comment: Not an answer, but a typical solution to this problem is to have the device start in AP mode when there are no wifi credentials available so that people can connect to it with a browser, enter wifi credentials, and then have it connect. No need to download thonny, transfer files, etc.

Comment: Also, what version of micropython are you working with? Support for WPS doesn't appear to exist in the primary repository (https://github.com/micropython/micropython).

Comment: Hiya. I'm just using the standard version, whatever is in/on the UF2 from Raspberry Pi - however I have in the last hour or so discovered that "Circuitpython" is a thing, so maybe there's something in there that could make it work? 

With regards to the AP point, I did try that, but I could not get it to work. I'm *very* new to coding so making this thing work up until this point has kinda taken a long time and everything - i've just sort of worked stuff out as I went and cobbled things together with a lot of trial and error, and google..

Comment: If WPS isn't an option ( I figured it'd be easier, since I can just write the WPS connection into the start of my program but.. aparantly not..) is there a 'plug and play' bit of code I can use to have the pico start up, start an AP, scan for wifi, ask the user to select their network and enter their password, and then close and run *my* program? I imagine then they can just use their phone to access the Pico's AP point to enter the info so the fact my device won't have a screen or keyboard would be a non issue.

Comment: I did try this approach before and got as far as an AP which sometimes worked and would have a form but I couldn't get the form to save the inputted information to a txt file (for my main program to read from) and nor could I get the server to actually launch and run my 'stockticker' program. I tried using import and the 'other' way (can't remember what that was but it didn't work!)

Comment: [This article](https://ansonvandoren.com/posts/esp8266-captive-web-portal-part-1/) documents one person's solution to this particular issue. There are others. If you want to open a new question with your AP-based code we can probably figure out how to get it working.

Comment: I'll definitely have a good full read of that - on a quick scan, it does look very interesting/relevant. But all things considered, based on the simplicity value of just having the user push a button vs get their phone out, connect, enter details etc.. if there is a way to make WPS work I feel like it'd be a really great option. It must be possible, somehow?